# Error using SAGA raster creation tools. Input layer error: points?

Tags: raster, saga

I have a shapefile containing x,y,z values as a point vector layer. I want to interpolate these points to create a DEM. For that I use SAGA natural neighbour algorithm. However, I am not successful and the log indicates that there is an error in the input layer, that I paste here:

> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.6\bin>saga_cmd grid_gridding "Natural Neighbour" -TARGET_DEFINITION 0 -SHAPES "F:/MarRisk/Entregable_UMinho/MRisK_Patos_Topo171108.shp|layername=MRisK_Patos_Topo171108" -FIELD "Z" -METHOD 0 -TARGET_USER_XMIN 514215.933 -TARGET_USER_XMAX 514681.748 -TARGET_USER_YMIN 4666855.922 -TARGET_USER_YMAX 4667258.189 -TARGET_USER_SIZE 5.0 -TARGET_USER_FITS 0 -WEIGHT 0.0 -TARGET_OUT_GRID "F:/MarRisk/Entregable_UMinho/MRisk_DEM_171108_5m_NN.sdat"
>
> Error: input file [F:/MarRisk/Entregable_UMinho/MRisK_Patos_Topo171108.shp|layername=MRisK_Patos_Topo171108]
>
> Error: Points

I don´t find any help documentation on the specifics of these algorithms to check if my data is wrong, but as I understand a point layer should be the requisite input.

Any advice?

My system is:

```
Win10, 64 bit
QGIS 3.6 64 bit
SAGA 2.32.2
```

Comment: Do you have duplicated points, by any chance?

Comment: No, I double checked. Funny thing is that to check I used a tool to remove vertices. It is a point layer, so it should not do anything. It created a new point layer, with the exact same number of points and values. If I use the nearest neighbour SAGA tool in the newly created layer it works..., and I don´t see any difference in them...

Comment: Interesting. Could you also test it by simply saving your point file as a new file? I am now thinking the original file may have wrong extent or something.